# What are the best practices for AWS Elastic IP addresses resiliency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-ip

We use Elastic IP addresses for our customers that require a static IP address for whitelisting. We're currently working on implementing a multi-region active-active solution. Is there a way to have an Elastic IP address failover to another region? I would also like to know how often Elastic IP address go down?

We want an automated solution to handle this, so that our customers don't have to do anything on their end.

The [AWS documentation on Elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-eips.html) only address the operation of it and doesn't have any information of its resiliency.

Comment: How about AWS Global Accelerator: https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/?blogs-global-accelerator.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&blogs-global-accelerator.sort-order=desc&aws-global-accelerator-wn.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&aws-global-accelerator-wn.sort-order=desc?

Comment: Is this for inbound connections or outbound connections? Are your clients whitelisting your IP so you can connect to them, or so they can connect to you?

Comment: @MarkB This is for inbound connections. The clients are trying to connect to our system.

Comment: @JimmyVo in that case I agree with the above comment that AWS Global Accelerator is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you MarkB and MarkoE. I'll looking Global Accelerator